# I want my column-4(i.e. column with heading and description ) to apeear first in mobile view. I have tried using helper class col-sm-pull-4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container-fluid padding-zero hidden-xs" id="wooden-floor">

<div class="block-2-container section-container section-container-gray ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 block-2-box block-2-left wow fadeInLeft">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active">
     <img src=".\Images\Wooden flooring.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
   </div>

   <div class="item">
     <img src=".\Images\wooden-flooring.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
   </div>

   <div class="item">
     <img src=".\Images\wooden-flooring2.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
 </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 block-2-box block-2-right block-2-media wow fadeInUp">
                <h3>Wooden Flooring</h3>
                    <p>
                  Jaipur Flooring is one of the trustworthy suppliers of wooden flooring products in India. Jaipur
```

Flooring’s Wooden laminate flooring is strictly made as per European quality with Indian Climate
conditions to give our customer the best value for money and full satisfaction.

```
                 <p>
                   Our wood flooring options bring a wonderful design to your home offering unique versatility. Sourcing
```

the best laminate options from the best manufacturing companies in the world.

```
                 <p>
                   Jaipur Flooring’s Wooden Flooring options are applicable to residential spaces, office spaces and
```

commercial spaces which can withstand heavy traffic areas.
These laminate wooden flooring are prefect amalgamation of good quality, comfort, pleasing
designs, as well as affordability.

```
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please correct the question (codes going in description) and if possible please add a link to the page or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:
xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)

If you are targeting mobile views, you should use `col-xs-*`.